# Returning records from the last 3 months only in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a timestamp field. How do I get data from the last 3 months?

In particular, March is my current month let say, *03/2012*. I need to return records from the months March, February, and January only.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

3 months before today:

```
select * from table where timestamp >= now()-interval 3 month;
```

Start with first of month:

```
select * from table where timestamp >= last_day(now()) + interval 1 day - interval 3 month;
```

Comment: @StephenKloder : Could you please explain the query ?Here what is use of'interval 1 day'?

Comment: @AlwaysBTryin is it possible to get it through php using date() function?

Comment: when you say timestamp you mean the name of the column right?

Answer (score 15):

To get the first day of the current month, you could use this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

if current date is `2013-03-13`, it will return `2013-03-01`, and we can just substract 2 months from this date to obtain `2013-01-01`. Your query could be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE data >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that INTERVAL should be two months, not three months because three months will include the month before January.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using SQL Server (Oracle, MySQL and others have similar date functions), you can use the dateadd function to add or subtract an interval to the current date.

If you want a full three months, you can subtract 3 months from today :  `DATEADD(m,-3,getdate())`

But, as you state, you only want data from January, February and March. You have to make some calculation based on today's date: `dateadd(m,-2, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(getdate()))  + '/01/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(getdate()))))`

And in the end, get a query like

```
SELECT fields 
FROM table 
WHERE timestampfield > DATEADD(m,-2, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(getdate()))  + '/01/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(getdate()))))
```

--- edit ---
erf, I just noticed the "mysql" tag...  you can get more information on MySQL date functions here :  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: the post says "only in MySQL"

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but to possibly save others time and to sum the above answers up for the case of needing (1) dates from current month and (2) dates from the prior 2 months (common when displaying data statistics):

```
WHERE ((timestamp >= NOW() - DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01'))
OR  (timestamp >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE your_date_column > LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code here to get the previous 3 months from a certain date

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column>= DATE_FORMAT(current_date(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 3 MONTH and date_column< DATE_FORMAT(current_date(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: just change the current_date() to your desired date.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select metric,MONTH(Created) as month,YEAR(Created) as year
from table
where metric = value
AND ( ( YEAR(Created) = YEAR(NOW()) AND DATE(Created) >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL :month MONTH) )
   OR ( Year(Created) = YEAR(NOW()) - 1 AND Month(Created) > MONTH(INTERVAL :month MONTH + NOW()) ) )
order by Created;
```

Mysql query to show last X months data.

Note :
This query wouldn't work if X > 12

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE ((timestamp >= NOW() - DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01'))
OR  (timestamp >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.