# How to get last 2 or 3 months data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I m trying to get last 2 and 3 months data.

e.g  Last 2 months data means Dec 2014 To Jan 2015 and 3 months means Nov 2014 TO Jan 2015
I tried

```
SELECT * FROM d_jobs WHERE  `job_date` >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -1 MONTH )
```

Here Its Count last 30 days data only .

So Which is the best way to perform this ?

Comment: Well if you ask -1 month, and it counts last 30 days, that seems logical, no? What happens when you ask -2 months?

Comment: I knw That. I want to fetch data from Dec 2014 to Jan 2015.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Query to get all rows from previous month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090221/mysql-query-to-get-all-rows-from-previous-month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM d_jobs WHERE  `job_date` >= last_day(now()) + interval 1 day - interval 3 month;
```

Comment: But it'll count only last 90 days records not 3 months records

Comment: Its works for 3 months.Can you please explain the query ?I wan to do this for 1 to 6 months

Comment: it gets the current date and minus 3 months from now

Comment: for 6 months just replace 3 to 6 or what do you want

Comment: Here what the purpose of 'interval 1 day ' I mean What is use of it ?

Comment: In my case it works i dont know: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397015/data-from-the-last-3-months

Comment: for six month you can do with SELECT CREATEDDATE FROM table_name WHERE CREATEDDATE >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 6 MONTH ;

Comment: 3 months before today:SELECT CREATEDDATE FROM table_name WHERE CREATEDDATE >= NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH;

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query hope you will overcome your problem i think

```
select * from d_jobs where job_date < Now() and job_date > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 3 MONTH);

select * from d_jobs where job_date BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND NOW();


select * from d_jobs WHERE job_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND NOW();
```

Comment: No Its not right for my case. e.g I want data from 1st Nov 2014 to 31st Jan 2015.Here what happen It'll count data from 7th Nov 2014. It should be start from 1st Nov

Answer (score -1):

Get left 7 chars of current date in ISO format (i.e. '2015-01'). Then add "-01" for 1st day of month (result is "2015-01-01"). Then use `INTERVAL ... MONTH` to get last months.