# fetch the data who's is not visited since last 3 month

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my Query.

```
    SELECT customer.*, feedback.*, feedback.id as fid
    FROM feedback
    JOIN customer ON customer.feedbackID = feedback.id
    WHERE feedback.Overall_rating !=  ''
    AND `feedback.fb_date != '2015-05-07' 
AND feedback.fb_date != '2015-08-05'
```

My Question is : How do I fetch the data of who has visited at least once before 3 months ago, and has not visited since.

Sorry for my English

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data from the last 3 months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397015/data-from-the-last-3-months)

Comment: what do u mean by "visited"? Do you mean a timestamp in database column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the questions correctly, you can use something like last_visit_date < Now - 90 days. Do you have access to the last_visit_date?

Answer (score 1):

If you completly rely on some "fb_date" you can use this where clause:

```
feedback.fb_date < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

To clarify, this would make the query:

```
SELECT customer.*, feedback.*, feedback.id as fid
FROM feedback
JOIN customer ON `customer`.`feedbackID` = feedback.id
WHERE feedback.Overall_rating !=  ''
AND feedback.fb_date < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

`feedback.fb_date` would need to be a DATE column type for this to work.

Comment: Hey Thanx basilup i have changes the query little bit but it it helps me a lot.