# Easy way to select records for last 3 months with 'datetime' column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table with a 'datetime' column, I want to choose the records from the last 'n' months

```
where and delta.datetime >= DATEADD(mm,-n,cast(GETDATE() as date))
```

does not work

Comment: [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15397107/1094092)

Comment: @billrichards: That's for mysql...

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Is there an error? Do you get wrong dates?

Comment: it returns no result

Comment: @mellamokb OP tagged the question with mysql

Comment: @billrichards: **@jpw** is the one doing the tagging.  I don't think `DATEADD` and `GETDATE` are even valid in mysql - this is clearly a SQL Server question.

Answer (score 0):

it worked I had to change the 'datetime' format to 'date'

```
date(delta.datetime)> DATE_SUB(date(now()),INTERVAL " . $gap . " DAY)
```