# How to move few months back from any retrieved date from query in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to move back from any given date. Help me in getting 3 months back date from given date.

I have tried DATE_SUB, DATE_ADD functions which do not return any result an keep running the query.

```
SELECT * FROM Table a 
INNER JOIN Tabel e 
on a.MobileNumber=e.Phone_number 
AND e.bill_date<a.invoice_date
AND  e.bill_date>DATE_ADD(a.invoice_date,INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
```

Query keep running and never stops. If i just remove the last condition, it shows the results in less than a second.

Comment: How large are these tables?  The answer to the performance question sort of depends on this.

Comment: One of them have 309 records and the other one have 1.8 M records.

Comment: Which record has 309 and which has 1.8 M?  Also, can you post the table definitions for both tables?

Comment: Table a has 309 records and Table e has 1.8 M records and I am trying to apply inner join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning records from the last 3 months only in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397015/returning-records-from-the-last-3-months-only-in-mysql)

Comment: @PathikVejani Not really a duplicate of that.  This question's answer would talk about optimizing the query, possibly using indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an index along the lines of the following might help the performance:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON table_e (Phone_number, bill_date, col1, col2);
```

Here `col1` and `col2` are the other two columns which might appear in the `SELECT` clause.  The strategy of this index, if used, would be to scan the relatively small `table_a`, which only has 309 records.  For each record in `a`, MySQL would then use the above index to rapidly find the matching records in the `e` table.

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` on the query.  Is the index being used?

Comment: I think query takes more time in computing value from DATE_ADD function which uses date from table_a which have only 309 records.
Adding index on table_e is not helping.

Comment: Edit your question and include both table definitions.  Obviously, if the index I suggested is not being used, my answer won't help you.

Comment: Well so many thanks @Tim Query at least showed me the results after 230 seconds. I'll try to investigate further if the index you suggested is used or not.

Comment: It sounds like it _is_ being used, but the index would be most helpful if it includes all the columns which would appear in `SELECT *`.

Comment: Your proposed solution rocked buddy! I missed a column last time while adding index but now it's working fine and got results in 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you can update then it is better to create `index` on `a.invoice_date` and . Please find the [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html) for the same.

Comment: Your proposed index does not cover the join condition.  Why do you think this would help?